# What is the purpose of the Snapshot in Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have the following sample python code to query Cloud Spanner:

```
from google.cloud import spanner

client = spanner.Client()
instance = client.instance(INSTANCE_ID)
database = instance.database(DATABASE_ID)
with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
    results = snapshot.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM Albums")
    for row in results:
        print(u"SingerId: {}, FirstName: {}, LastName: {}".format(*row))
```

I'm wondering what is the reason that a query and result-set needs to be run within a `snapshot` -- what exactly is a snapshot, and why couldn't, for example, the database be queried directly via a connection (or is the 'snapshot' an alias for a connection? Normally I'm used to initializing a db connection similar to the following pattern:

```
db = Connect(credentials)
connection = db.connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(...)
res = cursor.fetchall()
for item in res:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'snapshot' is a snapshot of the database at a given point in time. Using the same snapshot for multiple reads will guarantee that all data that is returned by those reads represent a consistent state of the database at a given point in time. So you can compare a `snapshot` to a (read-only) transaction.

Cloud Spanner always requires a snapshot or transaction for each operation, even if it is a single query. The default (and most efficient way to execute a single query) is to use a single-use read-only transaction. This is what is returned by the `snapshot()` function in the Python client. This snapshot can only be used for a single query.

Use `snapshot(multi_use=True)` if you want to create a snapshot that can be used for multiple queries.

Compare the following two samples:

1. Single query: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-query-data#spanner_query_data-python
2. Multiple queries: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-read-only-transaction#spanner_read_only_transaction-python